# Using rodriguez's formula to move coordinate (1, 0, 0) to (0, 1, 0)

Tags: linear-algebra

I've tried coding rodrigues' formula in python using the numpy library

```
import numpy as np
import math

def n_cross(x, y, z):
    return np.array([[0, -z, y], [z, 0, -x], [-y, x, 0]])

def Rodgrigues(n, angle):
    n_cross_array = n_cross(n[0], n[1], n[2])
    return np.identity(3) + math.sin(angle) * n_cross_array + (1 - math.cos(angle)) * n_cross_array * n_cross_array

r = Rodgrigues([0, 0, 1], math.pi / 2)

print(r)

print(np.multiply([1, 0, 0], r))
```

This is based on the following formulas

[image]

[image]

[image]

From what I understand, Rodrigues' formula yields a rotational matrix, so if you want to rotate a vector v about the axis n, you need to multiply the rotational matrix with vector v

To test if my code works, I've defined n as [0, 0, 1] (x is left and right, y is front and back, and z is up and down) and v as [1, 0, 0]. I want to rotate v, which is facing directly left, by 90 degrees, so it should be facing me, or [0, 1, 0]. This is the result I've gotten:

[image]

The top matrix is the value of the rotational matrix, which I've verified by hand, while the bottom matrix is supposed to be a 1 by 3 matrix which represents the rotated vector. I'm not sure why it's a 3x3 matrix. Ignoring the bottom matrix, I've multiplied the rotational matrix and vector v by hand, which yielded me back v instead of [0, 1, 0]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Matrix multiplication isn't np.multiply (or *), it's np.matmul (or @)!

Comment: It should be clear that something is wrong already from your “rotation matrix”, which isn't a rotation matrix at all (the columns are obviously not orthonormal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import math

def n_cross(x, y, z): 
    return np.array([[0, -z, y], [z, 0, -x], [-y, x, 0]])

def Rodgrigues(n, angle):
    n_cross_array = n_cross(n[0], n[1], n[2])
    return np.identity(3) + math.sin(angle) * n_cross_array + (1 - math.cos(angle)) * np.dot(n_cross_array, n_cross_array)

r = Rodgrigues([0, 0, 1], math.pi / 2)

print(r)

print(np.dot(r,[1, 0, 0]))
```

The above code works.

Use np.dot instead of * or np.multiply

Comment: At least for rotation axis being z axis, I checked it generates correct rotation matrix for all angles.

Comment: Well I'm getting [1,2,0] instead of [0,1,0]. It's not even getting rotated.

Comment: Test the corrected code by me.

Comment: Oh, my bad lol, I forgot to change line 9 as well, thanks!